# How to set value for a key in appsettings.json file during build time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

For my ASP.NET core solution, I have an appsettings.json file and it looks like this

```
{
  "Branch": {
    "Name": "test"
  },
}
```

If I want to replace value for "Branch.Name" to some other text, for example "prod" at *build* time. How do I achieve that?

EDIT: I am aware of the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environment variable and environment-specific appsettings file for .net core. But unfortunately, for some reason hard to explain, I still need to set value for a key in "appsettings.json" file at build time...

Comment: What does "build time" mean? Some services (e.g. DevOps and Octopus Deploy) support JSON substitution...

Comment: @KirkLarkin, I use bitbucket pipeline. Does it support JSON substitution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no built-in way to do this. I end up solving this by using jq. Read the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982333/json-value-substitution-in-bitbucket-pipeline).

Comment: also, I found SlowCheetah can be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how configuration works in ASP.NET Core. It works on an override system, so instead of literally changing values, you override those values with a more prominent source.

By default, `appsettings.json` is actually the least priority config source. It can be overridden by all of environment-specific JSON (`appsettings.Production.json` for example), environment variables, and/or command-line arguments.

For the purposes here, you should be looking at environment-specific JSON and/or environment variables. For example, if you create an `appsettings.Production.json` with contents:

```
{
  "Branch": {
    "Name": "prod"
  },
}
```

And then set your deployment environment to `Production` (i.e. `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable), then `Branch.Name` will be `prod` in that environment. Similarly, you can set a `Branch:Name` environment variable to `prod`, and this will also override the value.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am aware of the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environment variable and environment-specific appsettings file for .net core. But unfortunately, for some reason hard to explain, I still need to set value for a key in "appsettings.json" file at build time...

Comment: There is no mechanism for that. Therefore, it's probably a better idea to focus on the problem of why you think you have to, because there shouldn't be a need.