# JSON value substitution in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a JSON file "appSettings.json" which has the following content:

```
{
  "Branch": {
    "Name": "test"
  },
}
```

My question is, how do I set the value "Branch.Name" to something else when running the bitbucket pipleline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

figured it out after checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716734/modify-a-key-value-in-a-json-using-jq).

```
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -y jq # install jq
- tmp=$(mktemp)
- jq '.Branch.Name = "prod"' appsettings.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" appsettings.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Bash/Shell commands to do a 'Find and Replace' inside a text file:

#### Use `sed`

```sh
sed -i -e 's/"test"/"prod"/g' appSettings.json

# Delete the unwanted backup file, created by sed
if [ -e appSettings.json-e ]
then
    rm appSettings.json-e
fi
```

#### Use `echo` with Bash string substitution

Use this if you need to replace with special characters like "/" and "\", which `sed` cannot handle.

```sh
file_contents=$(< appSettings.json )
echo "${file_contents//\"test\"/\"prod\"}" > appSettings.json
```

More info and source: [Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command)